# Convert NSDict to NSDate

Tags: ios, date

I am trying to convert NSDict into NSDate. can anyone suggest some example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more information to understand this. What does the dictionary contain? How should those fields be mapped onto a date; in what time zone and calendar should the result be represented?

Comment: my dict contains a list of billdate, which are all in string format like mm/dd/yyyy.I need to convert every billdate as NSDate format.

Comment: so you need to convert a STRING to a date, not a dict at all :)

Comment: this is actually 100000 duplicated here on SO :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSSString *str = [dict objectForKey:@"billdate"];
NSDateFormater *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
f.locale = usLocale;
f.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy"; // The format string uses the format patterns from the Unicode Technical Standard #35

NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:str];
```

Comment: You should set the date formatter's locale to `[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]` before setting the dateFormat.

Comment: ok sounds reasonable, but I don't know... do I need to? :D doesn't it take the current user's locale?

Comment: For other locales the date format might be interpreted as dd/MM/yyyy or something totally different. If you **always** want the MM/dd/YYYY you have to specify the locale.

Comment: @thanks ill edit the answer

Comment: @user2022370  :: just curious as to why you revoked your acceptance of my answer and instead accepted an inferior copy -- the locale check is needed as fabian pointet out:)